# Replace NA in Factor type data in R

Tags: r

[image: Data Frame X]

The data frame X looks like this

```
State      code
New Jersey  1
New York    2
Califronia  NA
```

All columns are factors. I am looking to replace `NA` is with a text or 0. So that I can transpose them later.

When I try to run this command

```
X[is.na(X)] <- "0"
```

I get following errors

> ```
> Warning messages:
> 1: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, thisvar, value = "0") :
>   invalid factor level, NA generated
> 2: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, thisvar, value = "0") :
>   invalid factor level, NA generated
> 3: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, thisvar, value = "0") :
>   invalid factor level, NA generated
> 4: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, thisvar, value = "0") :
>   invalid factor level, NA generated
> ```

There is no change in `NA` values.

Comment: try `library(car);X$code <- recode(X$code, "NA = 0")`

Comment: `forcats::fct_explicit_na(X$code, 0)`

Comment: Thanks . My data frame has only factors.  I have few more columns with NAs. I am looking to change all NAs to "missing" or some text preferably.

Comment: @akaDrHouse - Not if *all columns are factors*, as OP states.  Bala, I think numeric columns should be just that, numeric.  There's really no reason they should be factors.

Comment: @RichScriven My suggestion was fail. I removed. However, the suggestion that data should or shouldn't be factors is a little presumptuous in my opinion.

Comment: Looking at your data it doesn’t appear that you `code` *should* be a factor. Why not a `numeric` or `integer`?

Comment: To change them all, `X[] <- lapply(X, forcats::fct_explicit_na, 'Missing')`, or to convert them to their appropriate non-factor types, `X[] <- lapply(X, function(x){type.convert(as.character(x), as.is = TRUE)})`

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative using built-in `factor`:

```
df <- data.frame(a=letters[1:3], b=c("d", "e", NA))
df
  a    b
1 a    d
2 b    e
3 c <NA>
```

Now, recode the factor with `factor`:

```
df$b <- factor(df$b, exclude = NULL, 
               levels = c("d", "e", NA), 
               labels = c("d", "e", "f"))
df
  a b
1 a d
2 b e
3 c f
```

And for many factors, the following may be useful:

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x){
  # check if you have a factor first:
  if(!is.factor(x)) return(x)
  # otherwise include NAs into factor levels and change factor levels:
  x <- factor(x, exclude=NULL)
  levels(x)[is.na(levels(x))] <- "0"
  return(x)
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
X$code <- as.character(X$code) #as.numeric works just as good
X[is.na(X)] <- "0"
X$code <- as.factor(as.numeric(X$code))
```

In a loop over all columns it would look like this:

```
for (i in 2:ncol(X)) {
  X[,i] <- as.character(X[,i])
  X[which(is.na(X[,i])==TRUE),i] <- "0"
  X[,i] <- as.factor(as.numeric(X[,i]))
}
```

And for a character value like this:

```
for (i in 2:ncol(X)) {
  X[,i] <- as.character(X[,i])
  X[which(is.na(X[,i])==TRUE),i] <- "Not Assigned"
  X[,i] <- as.factor(X[,i])
}
```

Or if you prefer not to transform to character first, assign a new level to each column:

```
for (i in 2:ncol(X)) {
  levels(X[,i]) <- c(levels(X[,i]), "Not Assigned")
  X[which(is.na(X[,i])==TRUE),i] <- "Not Assigned"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you wrote will work for matrices, if you don't mind converting back and forth.

```
> X
       State code code2
1  NewJersey    1    NA
2    NewYork    2     0
3 Califronia   NA     4

> X<-as.matrix(X)
> X[is.na(X)] <- "0"
> X<-as.data.frame(X)
> X
       State code code2
1  NewJersey    1     0
2    NewYork    2     0
3 Califronia    0     4

> str(X)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ State: Factor w/ 3 levels "Califronia","NewJersey",..: 2 3 1
 $ code : Factor w/ 3 levels " 1"," 2","0": 1 2 3
 $ code2: Factor w/ 3 levels " 0"," 4","0": 3 1 2
```

Answer (score 0):

let's create a random df with factor levels

```
df <- data.frame(a=sample(0:10, size=10, replace=TRUE),
                 b=sample(20:30, size=10, replace=TRUE))
df[df$a==0,'a'] <- NA
df$a <- as.factor(df$a)
```

other way to do is:

```
#check levels
levels(df$a)
#[1] "3"  "4"  "7"  "9"  "10"

#add new factor level. i.e 88 in our example
df$a = factor(df$a, levels=c(levels(df$a), 88))

#convert all NA's to 88
df$a[is.na(df$a)] = 88

#check levels again
levels(df$a)
#[1] "3"  "4"  "7"  "9"  "10" "88"
```